# Jenkins - Git Client plugin constantly cloning bare repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have some code in a plugin I'm writing that looks like so:

`newClient.clone(payload.getPullRequestSSH(), "origin", true, "");`
`newClient.checkout(payload.getPullRequestBranch());`

Essentially, I'm trying to clone a working repository (based off of an SSH url that I get provided from a GitHub webhook) and then check out a branch that's also specified from the webhook.

However, whenever I attempt this, the git-client plugin always clones a bare version of the repository that I cannot build from. Is there a way for the git-client to clone a working copy of the repo instead? The literal clone method makes no mention of this.

From the Git Client [Source Code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/GitClient.java#L307) for the clone command:

> Clone a remote repository
>
> url: URL for remote repository to clone
>
> origin: upstream track name, defaults to origin by convention
>
> useShallowClone: option to
> create a shallow clone, that has some restriction but will make clone
> operation
>
> reference: (optional) reference to a local clone for faster
> clone operations (reduce network and local storage costs)